# RestAssured: How can I get the RequestSpecification fields or parameters after sending a request?

Tags: java, java-8, cucumber, rest-assured, cucumber-java

I'm doing cucumber bdd tests i have a class `[MyClient]` that wraps restassured methods and I have multiple classes that calls `[MyClient]`.

I can do methods like put, post etc. just fine but I am wondering whether there is a way for me to get the actual **request** fields (header, body...) sent after doing the request.

I also dont have any problems getting and parsing the response but I'm unable to get the request sent.

Considering the following, I can call the `sendPostRequest()` that will store the `RequestSpecification` instance to a field called `request` and I can fetch it anytime by calling the `getter`. However, I cannot take the individual fields from the `RequestSpecification` object. From the `debugger`, I can see the fields just fine so I was thinking there has to be some clean way for me to get it.

I've already tried `log()` but it doesnt seem to give me what I need. 
Any help is appreciated!!

**CALLING CLASS:**

```
public class MyInterfaceSteps() {
 private myClient = new MyClient();

 public sendPostRequest(){
  myClient.post(someHeaders, someBody, someUrl);
 }
}
```

**CLIENT CLASS:**

```
public class MyClient() {
 private RequestSpecification request;
 private Response response;

 public getRequest() {
  return request;
 }

 public getResponse() {
  return response;
 }

 public Response post(Map<String, String> headers, String body, String url) {
  request = given().headers(headers).contentType(ContentType.JSON).body(body);
  response = request.post(url);  
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You create a filter (https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#filters) which gives you access to FilterableRequestSpecification (http://static.javadoc.io/io.rest-assured/rest-assured/3.0.3/io/restassured/specification/FilterableRequestSpecification.html) from which you can get (and modify) e.g. headers and body etc. The filter could store these values to a datastructure of your choice.

Comment: I wanted to be able to add the full URI of my requests to a testNG custom report. To do so, I had to do `FilterableRequestSpecification httpRequest = (FilterableRequestSpecification) RestAssured.given();`, then apply my query parameters with `queryParam(...)` and then do `.get(mypath)`. By casting the request to a `FilterableRequestSpecification` , without the need of a filter, I can finally access the URI with `httpRequest.getURI()`. Why is `getURI()` not a default method of RequestSpecification? Does casting it to FilterableRequestSpecification causes any trouble ?